# Trouble performing calculations on MySQL result sets

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to calculate the percentage of up votes for each record. Each record is coming out as 100 percent despite each record having a different number of votes.  Why is this happening?

```
$artistname = "SELECT * from voting";
$artistnameresults = mysql_query( $artistname ) or die( "Could not get video games " .mysql_error() );

for( $i = 0; $i < mysql_numrows( $artistnameresults ); $i++ ) {
    $data = mysql_fetch_array( $artistnameresults );

    echo "<div>". $data['artist'] ." has " . $data['votes'] ." votes ";

    if($total_votes > 0)
        $temp_votes = $data['votes']/$total_votes;
    else
        $temp_votes = 1;

    echo '( '.($temp_votes*100).'%)';
    echo "</div>\n";
}
```

Comment: Where is `$total_votes` coming from? That variable is never set, which means the `if` statement fails, and `$temp_votes` is set to 1, so the percent is always 100%

Answer (score 0):

you dont have anything in $total_votes..

```
$total_votes = $data['whatever_total_votes_is_here'];
if($total_votes > 0)
        $temp_votes = $data['votes']/$total_votes;
    else
        $temp_votes = 1;
```

if you don't have a count of the total votes in $data already then you will have to do a count or length to figure out the number.

pass that into total_votes so you can then do a check on it